# How does this natural sort function work?

Tags: javascript

```
function naturalSorter(as, bs){
    var a, b, a1, b1, i= 0, n, L,
    rx=/(\.\d+)|(\d+(\.\d+)?)|([^\d.]+)|(\.\D+)|(\.$)/g;
    if(as=== bs) return 0;
    a= as.toLowerCase().match(rx);
    b= bs.toLowerCase().match(rx);
    L= a.length;
    while(i<L){
        if(!b[i]) return 1;
        a1= a[i],
        b1= b[i++];
        if(a1!== b1){
            n= a1-b1;
            if(!isNaN(n)) return n;
            return a1>b1? 1:-1;
        }
    }
    return b[i]? -1:0;
}
```

Found this function in some legacy code. It works well, but I can't make sense of it. Could somebody explain what it is doing? Especially the regex part.

Comment: https://regexper.com/#%2F(%5C.%5Cd%2B)%7C(%5Cd%2B(%5C.%5Cd%2B)%3F)%7C(%5B%5E%5Cd.%5D%2B)%7C(%5C.%5CD%2B)%7C(%5C.%24)%2F

Comment: It's also hard to read because it's minified code (variable names, at least)

Comment: Vaguely this function converts the 2 strings into numbers and compares them according to numerical order. @JeremyThille It's not minified.

Comment: The variable names are all short, but I don't find any to have non-obvious meanings.

Comment: @Quentin That's bs :)

Comment: @JeremyThille — String version of `b`; the traditional name for the second of the two items currently being compared.

Comment: @Quentin I know. That was a pun ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an implementation of [natural sorting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_sort_order).

It's splitting strings into sequences of numbers, and comparing them. This enables `1-2` to be less than `1-3` to be less than `2-1`.